# Instantly update front end with new array value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm creating an app where users will send messages.  I have the messenger working but the front end isn't updating instantly when a new comment is entered.  You have to back out and then come back in to get it to show up.

I've researched examples and got the code from a course I took on udemy.  I've tried with tableview.reload() and tableview.insertrows().  I'm sending the data using JSON to PHP and MySQL.  It's showing in the db immediately but my code has it updating the UI first, it's just not working.

let messagetext = replyTxt.text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

```
    hhmessages.insert(messagetext as AnyObject, at: hhmessages.endIndex)
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.hhmessages.count - 1, section: 0)

    // update tableView
    tableView.beginUpdates()

    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()
    // scroll to the bottom
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)

    // empty textView and reload it
    replyTxt.text = ""
    textViewDidChange(replyTxt)
    let recipient = messages["username"] as! String
    let rid = String(describing: messages["recipient_id"]!)
    let uuid = messages["uuid"] as! String
    puuid = UUID().uuidString

    // prepare request
    let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/messagepost.php")!
    let body = "sender_id=\(user_id)&sender=\(username)&text=\(messagetext)&recipient_id=\(rid)&recipient=\(recipient)&uuid=\(uuid)&puuid=\(puuid)"

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)
```

The code should instantly update the UITableView with the latest comment and then commit to the database.  I've been trying for two days with no luck.  Any help is welcomed.

UPDATE WITH TABLE SOURCE CODE

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return hhmessages.count
}
   // Return cell to display on the tableView
// How many sections. Means numberOfSections * rows = view
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let colorSmoothGray = UIColor(red: 229/255, green: 229/255, blue: 234/255, alpha: 1)
    let colorBrandBlue = UIColor(red: 148 / 255, green: 33 / 255, blue: 147 / 255, alpha: 1)

    let pictureURL = hhmessages[indexPath.row]["uploadpath"] as? String

    // no picture in the post
    if pictureURL?.isEmpty == true {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ConversationCell
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi));

        isLoading = true

        let hhpost = hhmessages[indexPath.row]
        let smimages = hhpost["path"] as? UIImage
        let text = hhmessages[indexPath.row]["messagetext"] as! String
        cell.messageLbl.text = text
        cell.smavaImg.image = smimages

            cell.messageLbl.textAlignment = .right
            cell.messageLbl.backgroundColor = colorSmoothGray
            cell.messageLbl.textColor = .black
            cell.messageLbl.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.body)
            cell.messageLbl.font?.withSize(25)
            cell.messageLbl.clipsToBounds = true
              // get main queue to this block of code to communicate back
   DispatchQueue.main.async {

        cell.messageLbl.sizeToFit()
        tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi)
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)

    }
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PicCell", for: indexPath) as! PicConversationCell
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi));

        cell.smavaImg.image = smimages
        //if let message = messageData {
        for i in 0 ..< self.incoming.count {
            // Confiture the constraints for cell
            if self.incoming[indexPath.row] == 1 {
                                 // Constraints
               cell.lefBubbleConstraint.isActive = true
                cell.rightBubbleConstraint.isActive = false
                if cell.postpictureImg.image == nil {
                    cell.postpictureImg.backgroundColor = colorwhite
                    cell.postpictureImg.clipsToBounds = true

                }
                else {
                    cell.postpictureImg.backgroundColor = .clear
                    cell.postpictureImg.clipsToBounds = true

                }

            }
            else if self.incoming[indexPath.row] == 0 {


                // Constraints
                cell.lefBubbleConstraint.isActive = false
                cell.rightBubbleConstraint.isActive = true
                if cell.postpictureImg.image == nil {
                    cell.postpictureImg.backgroundColor = colorwhite
                    cell.postpictureImg.clipsToBounds = true

                }
                else {
                    cell.postpictureImg.backgroundColor = .clear
                    cell.postpictureImg.clipsToBounds = true

                }

            }

        // pictures logic
        let pictureString = hhmessages[indexPath.row]["uploadpath"] as? String
        let pictureURL = URL(string: pictureString!)!

        // if there are still pictures to be loaded
        if hhmessages.count != pictures.count {

            URLSession(configuration: .default).dataTask(with: pictureURL) { (data, response, error) in
                                  // downloaded
                if let image = UIImage(data: data!) {

                    self.pictures.append(image)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        cell.postpictureImg.image = image
                    }
                }

                }.resume()

            // cached picture
        } else {

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.postpictureImg.image = self.pictures[indexPath.row]
            }
        }

        }

        return cell

    }

}
```

Comment: What does the code beneath tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
do?

Comment: That line is to have the table go to the bottom of the view which is where the new messages are loaded.

Comment: how are you using your tableview? can you post the code for your uitableviewdatasource

Comment: I'll update with the table information.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the element to what your numberOfRowsForSection calls? Before you call insertRows the data source needs to be update.

Comment: I'm not using numberOfRowsForSection.  Any guidance on how I should use it?

Comment: @techgirl The tableView you’re inserting on should have it’s tableView.dataSource and tableView.delegate set. Whatever class you assign tableView.dataSource to should have a numberOfRows function in it. Have you set those properties up?

Comment: I have the table delegates and datasource connected through the IB.  I also have tableView.dataSource = self, tableView.delegate = self in the code.  I actually do have numofrowsin section:func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return hhmessages.count
    }

Comment: @techgirl Can you remove the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` around the insertRows you shouldn’t need them if you’re not performing multiple add/deletes on the table. Let me know if that fixes anything I’ve seen flaky ness when only doing one operation in a begin/endUpdates in the past.

Comment: I removed beginUpdates and endUpdates but no luck.  Still not instantly updating.  I updated my code above to show how i'm loading the tables.  Hopefully this helps.  Thank you so much for your willingness to help.

Comment: @techgirl If you just have your cellForRowAt code return a cell with a static label does it work? As an aside cellForRowAt should be called on the main thread to begin with so you shouldn’t need to dispatch certain parts off it.

Comment: I'm fairly new, right now I have it returning just 'cell'...are you recommending I hard code a value to see if it works?

Comment: Yes just return a basic cell with some text in it. Your cellForRow code seems fairly busy so could be many things in there creating issues.

Comment: I gave it a try...still stumped.

Comment: Sorry this is stumping me as well. If you’re still stuck on this tomorrow and you post the full view controller, backing models and data source for your code I’ll try and see what the issue is - assuming I have time.

Comment: Thanks @Justin - I'll post with that information.  Completely understand if you don't have time.